# Floobits error: no neovim python module

Tags: vim, neovim, vundle

I'm trying to install Neovim plugin for floobits (https://floobits.com/help/plugins/nvim), and after installing `:PluginInstall` in Vim, I get the error in the title. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? Here is my `~/.vimrc` file.

```
 set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
 filetype off                  " required

 " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
 call vundle#begin()
 " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
 "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

 " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
 Plugin 'floobits/floobits-neovim'

 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
 call vundle#end()            " required
 filetype plugin indent on    " required
 " To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
 "filetype plugin on
 "
 " Brief help
 " :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
 " :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
 " :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
 " :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
 "
 " see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
 " Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

 ...
 ...
 ...
 (The rest of the file is the same as here
 https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/vimrcs/basic.vim
 with the adition of the lines below at the end)

 " Configura arquivos html e javascript para identacao com 2 espacos
 autocmd FileType htmldjango setlocal sw=2 sts=2 et
 autocmd FileType javascript setlocal sw=2 sts=2 et

 " Configura linebreak automatico ao digitar a mensagem de commit
 autocmd FileType gitcommit set tw=72 colorcolumn=72

 " Desenha linha vertical vermelha em 110 caracteres para indicar limite
 autocmd FileType python setlocal textwidth=109 colorcolumn=110

 " Configura para mostrar o número das linhas
 set number

 " Permite circular pelas abas do vim usando Ctrl+Esquerda e Ctrl+Direita
 nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
 nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>

 " Aplicar PEP8 automaticamente a cada save dos arquivos python
 " 1) Instalar vim-pathogen (https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen - Aprox um package manager do vim):
 " mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
 " curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
 " 2) Instalar vim-flake8 dentro de ~/.vim/bundle (https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8)
 " cd ~/.vim/bundle && \
 " git clone https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8.git
 " 3) pip install flake8
 execute pathogen#infect()
 autocmd BufWritePost *.py call Flake8()
```

I made a symbolic link from `~/.vimrc` to `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, as according to https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#where-should-i-put-my-config-vimrc you can just create a symbolic link from your current .vimrc to that path.

I was also using pathogen as a vim package manager before using Vundle, and already ran

```
pip install neovim
pip3 install neovim
pip install neovim
pip3 install neovim
```

2 times: one for python virtual env, another globally, and for both python 2 and 3.

Comment: Did you try running `:CheckHealth`?

Comment: Same issue here. Are you on a Mac by chance? Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not a Mac ... using ubuntu 16.04. I ended up using neovim by running `nvim` instead of `vim`. Still get that error message every time I commit or rebase though. I can probably get rid of it by setting git to use nvim instead of vim.

Answer (score 0):

Try `:checkhealth` as a starting point.

My output told me that I had the Py3 module installed, but not the Py2 module.

Try:

```
pip2 install floobits
```

and then restart `nvim`.